# How to query data from entity object along with ICollection data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, code-first

I have these classes

```
public class CoffeeUser
{
    public CoffeeUser()
    {
        DrinkedCoffees = new Collection<DrinkedCoffee>();
    }

    public long CoffeeUserID { get; set; }

    public Guid Code { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DrinkedCoffee> DrinkedCoffees { get; set; }
}

public class DrinkedCoffee
{
    public long DrinkedCoffeeID { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateDrinked { get; set; }
}
```

How can i query for all items of DrinkedCoffees along with FirstName and LastName?
Result should look like this:

```
Tyler John 27.3.2012
Tyler John 28.3.2012
Tyler John 29.3.2012
```

I have tryed several queries but i was unsuccessful so far.

this was closest i was able to achieve:

```
    var list_4 = ctx.CoffeeUsers.Where(u => u.DrinkedCoffees.Count > 0).SelectMany(u => u.DrinkedCoffees).ToList();
```

Well, it took me 45 seconds to do this in sql. And 4 hours to not do it in entity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
  var DrinkedCoffies = ctx.CoffeeUsers.SelectMany(u => u.DrinkedCoffees, (u, cof) => new { FirstName = u.FirstName, LastName = u.LastName, DateDrinked = cof.DateDrinked } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an object called user that is an instance of CoffeeUser you should be able to do the following:

```
var drunkCoffees = from coffee in user.DrinkedCoffees
                   select new { user.LastName, user.FirstName, coffee.DateDrinked };
```

This will return you a collection of anonymous types containing the user last name, first name and when they drank a coffee.

**EDIT** Just reread your question - In your example with a data context you would need to do something more like this:

```
var drunkCoffees = from coffeeUser in ctx.CoffeeUsers
                   from coffee in coffeeUser.DrinkedCoffees
                   where coffeeUser.DrinkedCoffees.Count > 0
                   select new { user.LastName, user.FirstName, coffee.DateDrinked };
```

Here I'm selecting from your collection of CoffeeUsers and then from their collection of DrinkedCoffees where the count is greater than 0.

You can then display the results by doing:

```
foreach(var drunkCoffee in drunkCoffees) {

    System.Console.WriteLine(string.format("{0} {1} {2}", drunkCoffee.LastName, drunkCoffee.FirstName, drunkCoffee.DateDrinked));

}
```

Hope that helps!

James

Comment: James, thank you for very thorough answer. I have first seen Ashkan's post and used his solution and then later saw your. And your post actually clarified logic behind this problem. Thank you for that. I made Ashkan's answer as correct just because i used his solution first. Anyhow thank you for explaining this mess to me :)